# Random characters inserted in XML file over cellular data

Tags: ios, xml, cellular-network

I have an app that makes a request to an API, and then gets back an XML response which up until this week, I've had no problems parsing.  However within the last few days, when I make the request over AT&T's cellular network, random characters are being inserted into the response.  I've tested this over T-Mobile and Verizon and haven't had any issues, and WIFI is also returning a clean response.  I saw a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19020512/receive-xml-file-is-corrupted-on-sprint-network) about a similar issue with Android, but I don't think it's exactly the same.

Has anyone ever encountered something like this, or know how to prevent it?

Comment: If you are making a NSURL request, make sure you are using UTF8 encoding for your returned results. I was burnt with random characters in my xml for usign ascii encoding.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  Unfortunately I'm UTF8 encoding it in both my XML header: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> and in the NSURL delegate: NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:receivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];;

Answer (score 0):

EDIT
I found the solution from another question: [Remove wierd characters in xml output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25242784/remove-wierd-characters-in-xml-output)

You have to set the header for your content.  In your example it would be text/plain I think because it's xml.

```
<head>
  <title>Page name</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/plain; charset=utf-8"/>
</head>
```