# Four digit hash is showing up before each php include when using AT&T 4G network

Tags: php, lamp, 4g

As far as we can tell, only AT&T network requests are displaying this issue.

Before any php include that actually prints to the DOM, we are getting a variety of 4-digit (and sometimes 3-digit) hash codes such as 3288 and 3c14 displaying in the DOM (and on the web page).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, it turns out AT&T needs your headers when you're running an old LAMP stack.

Add the following to the .htaccess file:

```
Header set Cache-Control "no-transform"
```

Or you can set it specifically in PHP;

```
header("Cache-Control: no-transform");
```

We got to the solution through the help of [iOS Web page errors over Cellular Data but not over Wifi? Recent change to AT&T Cellular network?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25600332/ios-web-page-errors-over-cellular-data-but-not-over-wifi-recent-change-to-att) and  https://serverfault.com/questions/629981/android-browsers-adding-random-numbers-to-php-files