# No data for already purchased app when re-downloading

Tags: ios, xcode, icloud

One of my apps keeps data locally on the device instead of fetching it every time (it's quite a bit of data). It seems that with iOS 8, if you delete the app, or have to re-download the app after an update or device change - that when the "iCloud" button shows on the app store (meaning they have already purchased the app) - the app doesn't load any of this info, because the phone thinks it already has it. This happens no matter how many times you try to re-download the app.

The app loads fine with a new purchase.

I think i have fixed the bug, but is there anyway to test this?

Comment: How do you detect that you need to download the content?  It isn't "the phone" that thinks it already has the data - it is your app.  The behaviour should be the same whether the app is installed from the store or from Xcode - simply install the app, delete it and re-install from xcode

Comment: Found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25600332/ios-web-page-errors-over-cellular-data-but-not-over-wifi-recent-change-to-att