# Web Application not working in iphone with ATnT connection

Tags: iphone, amazon-ec2

I ran into a strange issue with a web application. It is on http protocol and hosted in amazon EC2 server. It is smoothly accessible from all phones and networks, except **iphone with ATnT network**.

I have even tried [this stackoverflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25600332/ios-web-page-errors-over-cellular-data-but-not-over-wifi-recent-change-to-att) :

```
Header set Cache-Control "no-transform"
```

But still facing the issue with loading web application with iphone and ATnT.

Comment: Does the same phone work fine over WiFi. Does the site work when connecting using another device tethered to your iphone. If you can answer those two questions it will tell you whether its the phone, the connection or the combination. I guess there could be a specific bug but its likely you need more information to properly debug what's happening.

Comment: It works fine over WiFi. Also on any other service providers, its working fine. It just the iphones using internet over ATnT face the isuue.