# Redirect loop only on iPhone, and only when using mobile data

Tags: php, iphone, wordpress

I have a site that, when certain links are clicked, gets sent into an infinite redirect loop rather than going to the linked page.  But it is only happening to iPhone users.  And only when they have wifi turned off.  It doesn't happen when they're connected to wifi.

I cannot recreate the issue in Browserstack.  And I've confirmed that the links work fine in Android, both on wifi and mobile data. It's a WordPress site with standard Rewrites in the .htaccess file, so no culprit there.  And there's no mobile detection going on either in PHP or JS.  If there were, I would expect this to be a problem with all mobile users.

I'm stumped.  Has anyone ever heard of this problem? If not, does anyone have any suggestions for debugging tools for a situation like this?  I run Windows 10 & Ubuntu. I don't have access to a Mac nor an iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

I finally sorted it out.  "Cache-Control: no-transform".  Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25758842/1401755